# Rotate a Vector3f arond a vetor3f with angle

Tags: math, vector, rotation, lwjgl

How can I rotate a vector3f around another vector3f with x angle (maybe quaternion)?
I do not want to use matrixes if posiible.

Comment: Use trigonometry functions, like sine and cosine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an [axis/angle rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle), you can use [Quaternion Rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation) instead.  I don't know much about lwjgl, but you may be able to find what you need in the [javax.vecmath.Quat4f](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Quat4f.html) or [javax.vecmath.AxisAngle4f](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/AxisAngle4f.html) classes.